# Loading an external PHP file with an internal PHP include function by using jQuery's 'load()'

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-load

I have a site under development with a "News" section and an "Older News" section. The news are stored individually in external [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) files which are loaded by the server by PHP (the server counts the number of PHP files and displays the last one – the current news – in the "News" sections and all the others in the "Older News" section:

```
<!-- ####### NEWS ####### -->

<div id="news">
    <h2>NEWS</h2>

    <div>
        <a id="showoldnews" href="#news">OLDER</a>
    </div>

    <?php $directory = "assets/news/"; if (glob($directory . "*.php") != false) { $newscount = count(glob($directory . "*.php")); } else {} ?>

    <?php include('assets/news/news' . $newscount . '.php'); ?>

    <!-- ####### OLDER NEWS ####### -->

    <div id="oldnews">
        <h2>OLDER NEWS</h2>

        <?php
            $newscount = $newscount-1;
            while ($newscount>0) {
                include('assets/news/news' . $newscount .'.php');
                --$newscount;
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

The "Older News" section is initially hidden and only made visible by a jQuery trigger:

```
// Show old NEWS
$('a#showoldnews').click(function () {
    $('#oldnews').show(400);
});
```

But I am expecting problems in long-term: since all news are loaded in the first place, this means that with more and more news coming up the website will be loading slower. And even if it's "acceptable", it's still not the ideal solution.

I was thinking on using `jQuery.load()` to load an external PHP file that would then load the old news only when the user asks for it.

The problem is that I don't know if its possible to load the following script by using `jQuery.load()` after the user clicks on a link:

```
<?php
    $directory = "assets/news/";
    if (glob($directory . "*.php") != false) {
        $newscount = count(glob($directory . "*.php"));
    }
    else {
    }
?>
<?php
    include('assets/news/news' . $newscount . '.php');
?>
```

It this approach acceptable? I have tried, but it didn't work at all (I could load static content with the `load()` function, but I was not able to make the server process the PHP script. I don't know if it's possible to make the server process the PHP code, because PHP processing is done on the the server side before the website begins loading... which is not the case.

UPDATE #1

I have the following that loads the 'load.php' file from the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#oldnews').load('load.php');
</script>
```

The content of the load.php file is:

```
<div class="section" id="oldnews">
    <h2>OLDER NEWS</h2>

    <div class="topLink">
        <a href="#">TOP</a>
    </div>

    <div class="topLink2">
        <a id="hideoldnews" href="#news">HIDE</a>
    </div>

    <?php
        $newscount = $newscount-1;
        while ($newscount>0) {
            include('assets/news/news' . $newscount .'.php');
            --$newscount;
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

The "TOP" and "HIDE" links appear without any problems. However, the PHP block seems to not be processed at all...

Comment: if you're asking your server to serve data, it doesn't matter how it does it. short answer, yes it should work, long answer, just make sure your syntax is correct. if $.load() doesn't work, try using an AJAX function like $.ajax() or $.post()

Comment: just remember that each call back to the server is its own process, meaning that the PHP script that processes the call will have to do all necessary includes relevant to your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP ***can*** be run before jQuery grabs the content... Here is what I setup and tested...

#### test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="feeds"><b>45</b> feeds found.</div>
        <script type="text/JavaScript">
            $("#feeds").load("go.php");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### go.php

```
<?php
    echo 'Hi';
?>
```

And the result is that `#feeds` `.innerHTML` is "Hi"... I would love more information/code in replicating the situation. It might help to take a peek at [the jQuery load API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: Thanks. Somehow it isn't working for the php include function. I have updated the original post.

Comment: @BMM Where do you set the "$newscount" php variable in your load.php file?

Comment: Dear Joseph. I was just figuring that out! It was declared before but it seems that I need to declare it in the external php file... that worked. Thanks for your help, I believe now everything should work ok... just a few tests...

Comment: @BMM Glad to hear it worked ... mind accepting my answer if all the tests come clean? Let me know it you run into any issues

Comment: It works :) now the problem is a different one... since I am using Cufón fonts, the Cufón engine is not applied to the contents of this external file... I need a way to force a Cufón reload. But I think I have read somewhere on how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @joseph told its correct and helped me, but in mycase i wanted to hide the content of the External Php file, 

Below is my code changes which had helped me !

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <b>Db file result</b>
        <div id="feeds" hidden=""></div>
        <script type="text/JavaScript">
            $("#feeds").load("db.php");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Php file had database connection so i had to hide it,
*db.php*

```
<?php

session_start();

$db = pg_connect("host=ec2-xxx-x0-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=dxxxxxxxxx user=vxxxxxxxxxx password=1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd");
 pg_select($db, 'post_log', $_POST);


 $query=pg_query("(SELECT id,name, FROM organization WHERE is_active = 'true' AND account_token = '".$_SESSION['account_token']."');


 $json=array();
while ($student = pg_fetch_array($query)) {
    $json[$student["is_user"]."-".$student["id"]] = $student["name"]."-".$student['pan'];
}

$textval = json_encode($json);
$foo = "var peoplenames=" . $textval;

file_put_contents('autocomplete-Files/'.$_SESSION['account_token'].'.js', $foo);

echo "<script>location='filename.php'</script>";


?>
```